# datareader vs bcp?

Tags: c#, sql

For reading the data from the database which is faster [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) or Data reader? The data will be around 50,000 records the size will be approximately around 170 MB. Please let me know if you need any more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), it is designed for buffering DataSets in memory:

> Using the DataReader can increase application performance both by retrieving data as soon as it is available, rather than waiting for
>   the entire results of the query to be returned, and (by default)
>   storing only one row at a time in memory, reducing system overhead.

Assuming you are consuming the data in a application and not writing an export application, then BCP would only slow you down. BCP would be the appropriate choice if you were only concerned with doing an export.

Answer (score 0):

what do you need to do with the data? You should use BCP if you want to export to a text file for example.

Data reader is a component you would use on a .net application to display data on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

`DataReader` still the more appropriate.I think BCP is another tool and has another role